# TCA Suggest Wizard with select field (side by side)

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x, typo3-tca

In a TYPO3 8.7 Backend / TCA, I'm trying to add a suggest wizard to a select field of the type `selectMultipleSideBySide`.

There are already two other wizards, add and edit, which work, while suggest doesn't.

```
'genres' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'label' => 'Genres',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_genre',
                'MM' => 'tx_myext_project_genre_mm',
                'size' => 10,
                'autoSizeMax' => 30,
                'maxitems' => 9999,
                'multiple' => 0,
                'wizards' => [
                    '_PADDING' => 1,
                    '_VERTICAL' => 1,
                    'edit' => [
                        'module' => [
                            'name' => 'wizard_edit',
                        ],
                        'type' => 'popup',
                        'title' => 'Edit', 
                        'icon' => 'EXT:backend/Resources/Public/Images/FormFieldWizard/wizard_edit.gif',
                        'popup_onlyOpenIfSelected' => 1,
                        'JSopenParams' => 'height=350,width=580,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1',
                    ],
                    'add' => [
                        'module' => [
                            'name' => 'wizard_add',
                        ],
                        'type' => 'script',
                        'title' => 'Create new',
                        'icon' => 'EXT:backend/Resources/Public/Images/FormFieldWizard/wizard_add.gif',
                        'params' => [
                            'table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_genre',
                            'pid' => '###CURRENT_PID###',
                            'setValue' => 'prepend'
                        ],
                    ],
                    'suggest' => [
                        'type' => 'suggest',
                        'tx_myext_domain_model_genre' => [
                            'maxItemsInResultList' => 25,
                        ],
                        'default' => [
                            'searchWholePhrase' => 1
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

I admit I got the code for the suggest wizard from a group field (where it works). But I need the side by side view in the backend, not the group view.

What I now get is

[image]

But I'd like a search box on top of it. 
Where can I find some example code?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out what I wanted is not the a wizard at all! 
But a so called `MultiSelectFilterTextfield`

Simply adding `'enableMultiSelectFilterTextfield' => true,` to config did the trick, so

```
'genres' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'label' => 'Genres',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_genre',
                'MM' => 'tx_myext_project_genre_mm',
                'size' => 10,
                'autoSizeMax' => 30,
                'maxitems' => 9999,
                'multiple' => 0,
                'enableMultiSelectFilterTextfield' => true, // <---- HERE
                'wizards' => [
                    '_PADDING' => 1,
                    '_VERTICAL' => 1,
                    'edit' => [
                        'module' => [
                            'name' => 'wizard_edit',
                        ],
                        'type' => 'popup',
                        'title' => 'Edit', 
                        'icon' => 'EXT:backend/Resources/Public/Images/FormFieldWizard/wizard_edit.gif',
                        'popup_onlyOpenIfSelected' => 1,
                        'JSopenParams' => 'height=350,width=580,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1',
                    ],
                    'add' => [
                        'module' => [
                            'name' => 'wizard_add',
                        ],
                        'type' => 'script',
                        'title' => 'Create new',
                        'icon' => 'EXT:backend/Resources/Public/Images/FormFieldWizard/wizard_add.gif',
                        'params' => [
                            'table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_genre',
                            'pid' => '###CURRENT_PID###',
                            'setValue' => 'prepend'
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Will produce

[image]